# Is it possible to tap a wire without breaking it?

Tags: current-measurement, hall-effect

There are plenty of ways to connect to a wire and measure what is going through it that involve breaking the insulation around the wire (such as positap connectors).

It is my understanding that a wire with current flowing through it creates a magnetic field around the wire. Could this effect be used to measure the amount of current flowing through a wire without breaking them? If so, can it be done with a small enough component to make it comparable to positap connectors?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. It's not as accurate.

Comment: Yes, you can measure the amount of current using a clamp meter, usually the currents need to be relatively high, its mostly used in industrial applications where you need to measure high currents without breaking the cable.

Comment: Hall-effect sensors are pretty common, there are probes for oscilloscopes and for DMMs. The clamp is less than 10mm long in many cases.

Comment: i.e.  How does a current clamp work? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341156/how-does-a-dc-clamp-meter-measure-current/341166#341166

Answer (score 2):

[Current clamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_clamp) are a mature product category. They are best suited to measuring AC or transient signals.

Comment: And there are instrumentation DC current clamps that measure down to microamps DC.  Generally used for non invasive testing on current loops.